# Rocket CORS how to return string with Request Guard?

Tags: rust, cors, rust-rocket

I have a rocket ([`0.5.0-rc.1`](https://crates.io/crates/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1)) route, that returns a `content::Json<String>` and I would like to add CORS to that route using [`rocket_cors`](https://crates.io/crates/rocket_cors) (from master).

Specifically I want to use the [`RequestGuard`](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors/0.5.2/rocket_cors/#request-guard), because I only want to enable CORS for certain routes.

My original request looked like this:

```rust
#[get("/json")]
fn json_without_cors() -> content::Json<String> {
    let test = Test {
        field1: 0,
        field2: String::from("Test"),
    };
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&test).expect("Failed to encode data.");

    content::Json(json)
}
```

and I changed it to use CORS (based on this [example](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/blob/dfd3662c49e2f6fc37df35091cb94d82f7fb5915/examples/guard.rs#L8)) like so

```rust
#[get("/json")]
fn json(cors: Guard<'_>) -> Responder<'_, '_, content::Json<String>> {
    let test = Test {
        field1: 0,
        field2: String::from("Test"),
    };
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&test).expect("Failed to encode data.");

    cors.responder(content::Json(json))
}
```

Unfortunately this now fails to compile with:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `cors`
  --> src/main.rs:35:10
   |
28 | fn json(cors: Guard<'_>) -> Responder<'_, '_, content::Json<String>> {
   |               --------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `cors`: `Guard<'static>`
...
35 |     cors.responder(content::Json(json))
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0621, E0759.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0621`.
error: could not compile `cors_json`
```

I can't give `Guard` a `'static` lifetime, because this leads to further issues down the road.

How can I return a `content::Json<String>` from my request with CORS?

A full example can be found on [Github](https://github.com/FrankenApps/rocket-cors-json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the fact that `rocket_cors` has lifetime bounds on the `Responder` struct, and these make the struct covariant on these lifetime bounds (so it makes it reject a `'static` lifetime when it shouldn't).

The good news is that these bounds are not necessary on the struct's declaration since they can exist solely on the related `impl` blocks.

I've [created a pull request](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/pull/97), but this will be a breaking API change since `Responder` will no longer be *directly* generic over these lifetimes. If you want to keep tracking their master branch, you can do what @Hadus suggested and pass a `'static` as the Responder's lifetime param.

Using the PR's branch you can directly do:

```rust
#[get("/json")]
fn json(cors: Guard<'_>) -> Responder<content::Json<String>> {
    let test = Test {
        field1: 0,
        field2: String::from("Test"),
    };
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&test).expect("Failed to encode data.");

    cors.responder(content::Json(json))
}
```

**Update: It's been merged.**

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could solve it was with some trial and error but here we go:

```rust
fn json(cors: Guard<'_>) -> Responder<'_, 'static, content::Json<String>>
```